# Rails model relationships saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, save, relationship

I have two classes with a many to many relationship, experiment and Sample:

```
class Experiment
  has_many :ExperimentSamples
  has_many :Samples, through: => :ExperiemntSamples

  # To avoid duplicate pointers to same sample in samples array
  def add_sample(sample)
    samples.each do |exp_sample|
      if sample.id && (sample.id == exp_sample.id)
        samples.delete(exp_sample)
        break
      end
    end

    samples << sample
  end
end

class ExperimentSample
  belongs_to :Experiment
  belongs_to :Sample
end

class Sample
  has_many :ExperimentSamples
  has_many :Experiments, through: => :ExperimentSamples
end
```

I have a method that creates and/or updates experiments and its related objects.  When I create or save an experiment, it creates/saves all the samples contained by the experiment as well.  Until today, that is, when a QA person submitted a change that updated an experiment, one of its samples, and a added another new linked object to that sample.  When the system saved the experiment object, the experiment field changes were saved, and the new linked object on the sample was created, but the sample object's changes were lost.  When I execute it again, but loop over and save each of the experiment's samples explicitly, everything works fine.

So, I've had a fundamental misunderstanding about how Rails saves linked data.  I'm guessing that new model objects are saved when linked to another saved object, but updates need to be handled explicitly, but can someone confirm this for me?

Also, I tried adding :autosave => true to the link in the experiment class and that didn't resolve anything. Shouldn't that have forced the issue?  [I realize now that I don't remember if I put it on the join table link or the :through link - maybe I just put it on the wrong one?]

I'm sure this is all available somewhere in the documentation, but at this point, I'd really just like a clear, simple explanation for my situation, instead of inferring it from something sort of related, or spending hours searching for exactly the piece of information I need.

Comment: how do you fetch the existing Sample record while editing its related Experiment record?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but the calling code supplies an XML string with the nested structure of the objects.  The Experiment class has a static method to construct the experiment (it retrieves it by ID from the database), and it passes the nested sample XML to the Sample class's static constructor method to retrieve the appropriate sample.  The experiment method adds the resulting sample object to its samples array.  I can update my code sample if it will help, but I was afraid it would be too much clutter.

Comment: Okay, looking at the code, maybe I got too smart for my own good.  To avoid duplicating samples in an experiment, I have an add_sample method in the Experiment class.  It loops over the samples, and if it finds an existing sample with the same ID, it deletes it from the array, so that when the incoming copy is added, it'll be unique.  Perhaps I need a better way to do this.

I added this code to the OP.